# how to find the number of couples of points

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I am trying to find out how I should calculate the number of couples of points but I currently hanging to translate it into an equation.

For example:

Given the following points $\{A, B, C, D\}$ the result should be 6:

$$(A,B),
(A,C),
(A,D),
(B,C),
(B,D),
(C,D).$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want the number of couples which can be formed from n objects, that is the binomial number $\big({n\atop2}\big)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you please write this as an answer so I may accept it.

Comment: Don't mind for that. I'd rather appreciate you to edit your question to make clear that you are looking for the number of couples of points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways to choose an (unordered) subset of $k$ elements from a fixed set of $n$ elements is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):
$$
\binom nk=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k!)}.
$$ 
In your case $k=2$.